# How to change theme of flutter app Which appears when minimized

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to chnage the color of the app bar when minimized. I have tried

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  title: 'FunHolidays',
  home:Entry(),
  ),);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `primaryColor` to override the default color

```
ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.green,
      ),
```